# Websocket with authentication serial with js and perl

Tags: javascript, perl, authentication, websocket

I am using plain js (no library) to implement websocket connection to the server (to PERL script). 
Looking online I found that it is possible to add custom parameters in URL request as follows:

```
var ws=new WebSocket('wss://mydomain.com:9999/?UserID=329729');
```

My question is: How then in PERL's NET::WebSocket::Server I can handle this query string to retrieve the UserID in handshake (if even possible)?

```
Net::WebSocket::Server->new(
    listen => $ssl,
    silence_max=>3600,
    on_connect => sub {
        my($serv,$conn)=@_;
        $conn->on(
            handshake => sub {
                my($conn,$handshake)=@_;

                # ???



            },
        );
    }
)->start;
```

Any help can be appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::WebSocket::Server) you have multiple examples. One of these uses the `handshake` event as follows:

```
    ...
    $conn->on(
        handshake => sub {
            my ($conn, $handshake) = @_;
            $conn->disconnect() unless $handshake->req->origin eq $origin;
        },
```

By following links to [more documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::WebSocket::Server::Connection) you can see that `$handshake` in the handshake event is a [Protocol::WebSocket::Handshake::Server](https://metacpan.org/pod/Protocol::WebSocket::Handshake::Server) object and the (currently undocumented) `req` method used in the above example probably leads to a [Protocol::WebSocket::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/Protocol::WebSocket::Request) object. The documentation for this class mentions an undocumented `resource_name` method but the example provided for this class suggests, that this is the path component of the URL, i.e. `/?UserID=329729` in your specific question.

Based on this I would suggest that the following should work with your specific URL:

```
    $conn->on(
        handshake => sub {
            my($conn,$handshake)=@_;
            my ($id) = $handshake->req->resource_name =~m{\?UserID=(\d+)};
```